# swift: access variable inside else statement

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to access a variable I'm creating in if statement in else. For example:

```
if let filePath: NSURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myFile.txt"){
```

But I can't access to the variable filePath in else block:

[image]
Any of you knows how can access the variable filePath inside the else block?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: The variable would have the value `nil` inside that `else` block, because that's the only way to get into that `else` block. So just print `nil` in there if you really want to print something.

Comment: filePath will be initialized and hold a value only if `documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myFile.txt")` returns a `non-nil` value. If it returns `nil` value, `else` block will be executed. Simple scope understanding.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you need that `filePath` variable in else block as it is nil if condition is not true and if you gonna access that you got an error ..so better to leave just an error message without `filepath` variable... You can also use `guard` statement here to access variable

```
   guard let filePath = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myFile.txt") else {
        continue 
   }

    // continue with filePath
```

Comment: For example if I want to print the filePath inside the else the variable is not available even using guard

Comment: yes, you can't use it ..  as there is of no use of it because it gives you nil

Comment: @user2924482 I would say you can't ... so just don't think about that and if you can somehow you got an error

Answer (score 3):

To clear up why you can't:

In an `if let x = foo` statement, `x` is only ever visible *inside the if block*. That is because the if block runs when `x` could be created, but when it can't be created, the else block will run (or code will continue if no else block exists).

As others have mentioned, you may need to rethink what you're doing and the structure of your code.